# How get url download file`s in UserDirectory?

Tags: swift, alamofire

How to take the url of the file? or to see what files are in the User Directory?

```
   let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .UserDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
    Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://best-muzon.com/dl/NNE2IxI6LYNtocG2fmFn3Q/1442201485/songs12/2015/02/vremja-i-steklo-imja-505-(best-muzon.com).mp3", destination: destination)
        .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                //print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
                self.label.text = String(totalBytesRead)
            }
        }
        .response { request, response, _, error in
    }
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the destination directory – the `.UserDirectory` parameter – and the file name – the last path component of the URL

```
let url = "http://best-muzon.com/dl/NNE2IxI6LYNtocG2fmFn3Q/1442201485/songs12/2015/02/vremja-i-steklo-imja-505-(best-muzon.com).mp3"
let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
```

I don't know if `.UserDirectory` is the home folder (~) or the downloads folder (~/Downloads) but it's easy to concatenate the directory and the path and create a file URL either

```
let destinationPath = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAddingPathComponent(fileName)
```

or

```
let destinationPath = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAddingPathComponent("Downloads/\(fileName)")

let destinationURL = NSURL(filePath: destinationPath)!
```